# Getting exception from djangorestframework

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following exception from djangorestframework's JSONEncoder class:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  72.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py" in render
  106.             allow_nan=not self.strict, separators=separators

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/json.py" in dumps
  28.     return json.dumps(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py" in dumps
  238.         **kw).encode(obj)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py" in encode
  199.         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py" in iterencode
  257.         return _iterencode(o, 0)

File "/home/ubuntu/Envs/env_md/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/utils/encoders.py" in default
  56.         elif (coreapi is not None) and isinstance(obj, (coreapi.Document, coreapi.Error)):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /v0/ui/website/subject-assignment/
Exception Value: module &#39;coreapi&#39; has no attribute &#39;Document&#39;
```

So, basically, it is saying my application (coreapi) does not have Document attribute. All the other apis are working fine but it is giving this error in one particular api. I can't find anything different with that api as well. Is there anything wrong with the  djangorestframework or any idea what should I do to debug?

Note: I am using django 2.1.4, djangorestframework==3.9.0 and python version is 3.6.5.

Comment: Do the other working APIs also share the same virtual environment `env_md`?

Comment: yes, there is only one environment I am using, and all the other apis are working apart from this.

Comment: You should use pdb to debug you code and check from where the exception is coming.

Comment: can you please share you code where actual error raised ?